# Umbraco sending email when form is submitted

Tags: asp.net, web-config, umbraco

I have an Umbraco website with a contact form that when submitted should send an email to a specified email address. It works fine when the 'to email' is on the same domain as the from email. However it throws this error when the 'to email' is on a different domain:

[image: YSOD error]

I was just wondering if there is something within Umbraco that I need to do to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is an umbraco issue.

You either have some kind of firewall on your mail server to intercept it (spam filter), or you might need to use another port.

Need more information about your mail setup if I am to help you more